# Soap api create request

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, cloud

I'm trying to create an entry using SOAP API create request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
     <fueloauth>7XsPrhS1j4eSJjXkeulOIYBA</fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>

<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Objects xsi:type="SentEvent">
         <SendID>213123</SendID>
         <SubscriberKey>SubscriberKey</SubscriberKey>
         <EventDate>2008-08-01</EventDate>
         <EventType>Sent</EventType>
         <BatchID>123321</BatchID>
         <TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID>123543453</TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID>
         <ListID>4312</ListID>
         <PartnerKey>153</PartnerKey>
         <SubscriberID>153</SubscriberID>
    </Objects>
 </CreateRequest>

  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As the result, I've got this error:

```
<StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
<StatusMessage>Specified method is not supported.</StatusMessage>
```

Does this mean that I don't have enough rights to perform this request?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to insert Sent Events into SFMC?  I really don't see ANY usecase for this. It also is not possible to do.  Also, next time don't include your Oauth token on the call - it can open risk that someone malicious can get into your system.

Comment: I already got the answer I wanted from Eliot, but it's kind from you to reply anyway. As for the reason, I'm extracting data from SFMC but we don't have any data in it. In order to get the structure, I need at least one valid entry. As for the token, I posted an expired one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a permission based issue.

The SentEvent object contains tracking data related to an email send, you can only use the Retrieve method with this object. Refer to supported methods of the [SentEvent object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sentevent.htm).